# MS Dynamics CRM 2016 Html webresource include references

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

IN MS Dynamics 2016 (V8) Html WebResource not acces the other JS files 
new_/JS/filename.js
and Html web resource name new_html.html

and reference path is

(script src="JS/filename.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8")

but it works on CRM 2015 and old versions

Comment: You could open the preview of all your items to figure out their actual path. Most likely your relative path does not match the path you created when uploading your web resources.

Comment: Relative path are same for all files 
http://crm-server/WebResources/new_/JS/filename.js

Comment: for Html
http://crm-server/WebResources/new_html.html

?

Comment: So you see that your JS files are in subfolder `/new_/` - change your reference path to `new_/JS/filename.js` and everything should work as expected.